# I need to see if an array is sorted using pointers on the beginning and the end

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, pointers

Implement isSorted.
The function must return true if a floating-point array is sorted in ascending order.
When called, pBegin points to the first element of the array and pEnd points to the last.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
//
//
bool isSorted(double *pBegin,   double *pEnd){
     int size=pEnd-pBegin;
     int sum=0;
     for(int i =0; i < size; i++){
         if(pBegin[i] > pBegin[i+1]){
             cout << "false" << endl;
             return false;
         }
     }
    cout << "true" << endl;
    return true;
}
//
// Ändra INTE här nedanför!
//
int main(){
    int size=3;
    double arr[]={-1.2 , 8.3 , 8.4};
    isSorted(&arr[0],&arr[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what problem are you having with this code? what doesn't work?

Comment: if it is sorted then it should write true but instead it is writing false

Answer (score 2):

you need to change the boundry check, try this:

```cpp
for(int i =0; i < size -1; i++){
    if(pBegin[i] > pBegin[i+1]){
        cout << "false" << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initial statement is wrong:

> When called, pBegin points to the first element of the array and pEnd points to the last.

Notice this:

```
isSorted(&arr[0],&arr[3]);
```

The element `&arr[3]` is one beyond the end of the array. So you have written code based on your initial statement and it accesses the `3` element (one beyond the end).

I would point out that in C++ when passing pointers (iterators) the end is usually one passed the end, so this looks normal. You just have to adjust your `isSorted()` function so that it does not accesses this element but stops one before.

So your loop should end one before `size`

```
     for(int i =0; i < size - 1; i++){
         //            ^^^^^^^^
         // Note: Normally `size` is correct.
         //       But inside the loop you accesses element `i+1`
         //       So you need to take that into account.
         if(pBegin[i] > pBegin[i+1]){
         //                    ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Rethink how you are solving this

Your instructions are to use pointers:

- one to the *first* element in your array,
- the other to *one past the last* element.

But then you go and use integer indexing anyway. This won’t fly when you are graded.

The whole point of the exercise is to *not* use integer indices. You must only use the pointers.

#### What can I do with pointers?

- You can dereference a pointer to access an element’s value.
   `*begin` → first element (element `0`) of the array (same as `begin[0]`)
- You can add one to a pointer to make it point to the next element:
   `begin++` → (now ‘begin‘ points to element `1` of the array)

You can use this knowledge to iterate over the array.

```
std::cout << *begin << "\n";  // print array[0]

++begin;
std::cout << *begin << "\n";  // print array[1]

++begin;
std::cout << *begin << "\n";  // print array[2]

...and so on...
```

The question is, how do you know when to stop?
Would the `end` pointer be able to help me here?

#### Iterators

This is the concept behind *iterators* in C++. An **iterator** is just an object that *looks* and *acts* like a pointer. It can, in fact, *be* a pointer.

Said another way, you have been given a pair of iterators for your array of `double`s. You use the first to access the elements of the array (to iterate over it). You use the second to know when to stop.

#### Fencepost errors

As already pointed out, the “end” (or “last”) iterator does not point to the last element — it points to *one past* the last element. In other words, it is invalid to use `*end`, since that would attempt to access an element outside the array.

```
[-1.2] [ 8.3] [ 8.4]
↑                    ↑
begin                end
```

This always seems to surprise people, but it is the same as if you were using integer indexing. You cannot access element *number* 3 of a 3-element array. You can access elements at indices 0, 1, and 2. But not 3, since that is past the end of the array.

```
--0--- --1--- --2--- --3---
[-1.2] [ 8.3] [ 8.4]
```

#### Printing output

You should not be printing anything from inside a yes/no function. The function returns a boolean value to the caller, and the *caller* then gets to decide what to print.

Your main function, then, should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>  // for std::extent<>

int main(){

    // declare our array and get its length
    double arr[] = {-1.2 , 8.3 , 8.4};
    size_t size = std::extent<decltype(arr)>::value;

    // determine whether the array is sorted
    //   and tell him/her what we learned
    if (isSorted(&arr[0], &arr[size]))
        std::cout << "array is sorted\n";
    else
        std::cout << "array is NOT sorted\n";
}
```